# rails3-jquery-autocomplete how to get field on joins table

Tags: join, ruby-on-rails-3.1, scope, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use joins() to retrieve datas from another table.
But after several tests (also with get_autocomplete_items) I don't find the solution !

Here is my last test :

My controller :

```
autocomplete :store, [:code], :full => true, :extra_data => ['city.name'], :scope => [:search_like_code], :display_value => :code_with_city
```

And my Model :

```
scope :search_like_code, lambda { |code|
  joins(:city).
  where("code LIKE ?", "%#{code}%")
}

def code_with_city
  return [code, city.name] * ' '
end
```

My log :

```
Unknown column 'city.name' in 'field list': SELECT  stores.id, stores.code, code, city.name FROM `stores`  WHERE (LOWER(stores.code) LIKE '%br%' ) ORDER BY stores.code ASC LIMIT 10
```

My query doesn't have the INNER JOIN so this error is normal.

Comment: I think in reading your log that your scope is not call. It's another scope call. What is your plugin you use on Rails ?

Comment: Yes my scope isn't call, I don't understand why ! My plugin is rails3-jquery-autocomplete and I follow the doc an the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation you can see the option to pass Scope is `:scopes` not `:scope`

So try with :

```
autocomplete :store, [:code], 
  :full => true, 
  :extra_data => ['city.name'], 
  :scopes => [:search_like_code], 
  :display_value => :code_with_city
```

Comment: Yes you right and after change "scope" to "scopes" I have another problem. Here is my log "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
autocomplete :store, :code, 
:full => true, 
:extra_data => [:name], 
:scope => [:search_like_code], 
:display_value => :code_with_city
```